# Why does an a-element styled as a button behave different than a button element?

Tags: html, css

I have a html `button` and want to replace it by an `a`. The style should stay the same. Furthermore I want to use the `center-block` class from bootstrap:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Minimal example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mdn5ahf/1/)

```
<a class="center-block">test</a>
<button class="center-block">test</button>
```

The result is, that the `button` is centered and keeps it's width, where the `a` changes to 100% width:

[image: result]

To figure out what the difference is, I added all user-agent styles from the button to the a-element. The result is the same. Here is the diff of the *computed* styles in chrome: [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/pshfak9s).
[image: computet css in chrome]

It has no differences which could cause the behavior.

What am I missing here?

Comment: add a display:inline

Comment: not sure why this got downvoted, seems a well written and valid question with an example

Comment: They behave different, because <button> is a replaced element and <a> is not. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the real problem but the `<a>` element is an inline element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) while your class . center-block makes it block.

just removing it you get the desired behaviour (don't know if you need that element block or  not)

```
.center-block {
  //display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mdn5ahf/2/)

Comment: Yes, so far so easy. But as I wrote: _Furthermore I want to use the center-block class from bootstrap._ But still: when they both are set to `block`, why do they look different?